# Ubuntu machine freezes completely

Tags: freeze, monitor, reboot

Everyday I experience a complete freeze of my PC. (I recently started using Ubuntu 18.04, and a freeze usually takes place once per day closer to the evening.)

By 'freeze' I mean that all of a sudden my monitor starts displaying the same frame without refreshing. My PC still works but monitor freezes, and thus I can't do anything, and I have to force shutting down my PC with a power button and rebooting it. I don't overload it or something: 2 days ago it happened when I tried to search for a file in 'nautilus', yesterday it happened when I selected some files in 'nautilus', today (just 5 minutes before I post this) it happened while browsing this exact website with 'chromium'.

It seems like what I was doing at the moment wasn't actually a deal for the freeze. But what was? I am using a rather old VGA monitor with VGA to DVI-D adapter for my GPU - RX 560. I believe it's not some kind of a bug, because I'm using just basic software (e.g. nautilus, chromium) and default drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post more details on your PC's configuration such as amount of memory, type of CPU, hdd or ssd etc. I have a Dell Inspiron 5675 Desktop PC with an AMD Ryzen 1700x CPU, 8 GB DDR4 Ram and Ubuntu 18.04 on a 500 GB ssd and an AMD RX580 graphics card. I get the same symptoms as you. Sometimes the usb keyboard will still be functional when the freeze occurs and I can use the Sysreq REISUB sequence to get out the the freeze and reboot gracefully. Other times both the usb keyboard and usb mouse are non responsive during the freeze. My syslog and kern.log files do not show anything before the freeze occurs so I am thinking it is an intermittent hardware problem.

I have tried using ssh to get into the PC from another machine when the freeze occurs but the connection is refused. I am slowly changing hardware bits and simplifying the configuration to see if it stops. It is a slow process since it can be a day or more between freezes. The same thing was happening with Ubuntu 16.04.4 on this hardware. So far I have changed the ssd, the OS (to 18.04 from 16.04 using a fresh install) and the mouse and moved the entire PC off my UPS power onto the mains power with no change - the random, intermittent freezes continue. Next I will change the power supply and the graphics card.

The PC passes all of Dell's built in extended UEFI hardware tests but given the intermittent nature of the freezing problem that doesn't surprise me. This is a very sly and slippery problem since I can't find a trigger for it.

Also found this bug report https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196683 which mentions the above symptoms caused by the C6 C-state of the Ryzen processors being turned ON. An apparent fix is to turn C6 OFF in the BIOS or in the Linux kernel or via a script run at start up as a cron job. This could be the culprit.